# CoreImage CIHardLightBlendMode issue

Tags: ios, core-image

I would like to use the filter CIHardLightBlendMode but it doesn't seems to work as explained on the Apple website:

> If the source image sample color is lighter than 50% gray, the
>   background is lightened, similar to screening. If the source image
>   sample color is darker than 50% gray, the background is darkened,
>   similar to multiplying. If the source image sample color is equal to
>   50% gray, the source image is not changed

I have tried with a 50% gray overlay image and my result is darker.
I have tried with a 73% gray and there is almost no impact (as it should be with 50%)

The problem is I have a lot of existing overlay images that I currently use with ImageMagick and it is working correctly (the overlay images work also on Photoshop or Gimp using the Hard light overlay mode)
To process the images faster, I would like to use CoreImage but it is not working as I expect.

How can I use the filter as it is explained ?

Here is my code:

```
CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
CIImage *sourceImage = [CIImage imageWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:imgSource]];
CIImage *overlayImage = [CIImage imageWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:imgOverlay]];
CIImage *outputImage;

CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIHardLightBlendMode"];
[filter setDefaults];
[filter setValue:overlayImage forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
[filter setValue:sourceImage forKey:kCIInputBackgroundImageKey];
outputImage = [filter outputImage];

CGImageRef cgimg = [context createCGImage:outputImage fromRect:[outputImage extent]];
self.processedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimg];
CGImageRelease(cgimg);
```

Thanks